# Angular2 Typescript Confirmation popover

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i'm start learning angular2 + typescript and trying to find something like ng-really-message, ng-really-click (in Angularjs) when i'm click to delete button. Can someone propose me best way? and link to documentation.
P.S. I'm using asp.net core, .net core

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this easily without a need for an external module/directive:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
     <a (click)="confirm('Are you ready?', takeaction)">Delete Me</a>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
   confirm(msg, fn){
     let result = confirm(msg)
     if (result) {
       fn()
     }
   }

   takeaction(){
      console.log('Taking Action!!')
   }
}
```

Comment: can we discuss about this solution?

Comment: Did you try this out? Let me know what questions you had.